# Eclipse giving error "database disk image is malformed." while CLI pragma_itegrity check shows status OK

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, sqlite

I am using sqlite 3 db. The size of db has grown to 2GB. It was working fine. Suddenly eclipse started giving error while inserting data:

```
java.sql.SQLException: database disk image is malformed
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:115)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:37)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:217)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:206)
    at application.loginModel.interactWithDB(loginModel.java:205)
    at application.loginController.buttonAction(loginController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**EDIT:**
I opened sqlite CLI and did:

```
pragma integrity check;
```

and CLI status shows:

```
*** in database main ***
Page 65526 is never used
Page 65527 is never used
Page 65528 is never used
Page 65529 is never used
Page 65530 is never used
Page 65531 is never used
Page 65532 is never used
Page 65533 is never used
Page 65534 is never used
Page 65535 is never used
Page 65536 is never used
```

What went wrong?

**EDIT 2:**
I restored the corrupted db using http://froebe.net/blog/2015/05/27/error-sqlite-database-is-malformed-solved/. In CLI the pragma integrity check shows status **OK** but in eclipse I am getting the same database disk image malformed error.

**EDIT 3:**
I have got the same error, on a fresh sqlite db. The only common thing between 2 db files was that both of them started showing this error after reaching a file size of around 2GB.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt database. Check [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html), and see if any of the items on there may have caused the corruption.

Comment: Do sqlite and the underlying filesystem support files that size?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I have restored the corrupted db, ran pragma integrity check and it shows status ok. But within eclipse I am still getting the same error. I am able to open db in sqlite browser without any issues.

Comment: @nitind I verified the limits. Yes they do.

Comment: @nitind Theoretically file size supported is huge, but I got the same error on 2 different dbs and common thing among them was both of them showed this error after reaching a file size of about 2GB.